# Two AWS Lambda functions with two IAM Roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I have two AWS Lambda functions. One should have access to Lambda policy and the other should have access to Lambda policy and SQS.

I'm trying to create the IAM roles so by default they have access to the Lambda policy and then for the second IA Role I try to attach the SQS policy.

I'm using the following HCL:

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "sqs" {
  name = "lambda-feeding-queue"
}

resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "sqs" {
  event_source_arn = aws_sqs_queue.sqs.arn
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.example.arn
  enabled = true
  batch_size = 1
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "example" {
  function_name = "ServerlessExampleBook"

  s3_bucket = "lambda"
  s3_key = "mn/v1.0.0/lambda-1.0.0-all.jar"

  handler = "dk.fitfit.handler.BookRequestHandler"
  runtime = "java8"

  memory_size = 256

  role = aws_iam_role.example.arn
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "event" {
  function_name = "ServerlessExampleEvent"

  s3_bucket = "lambda"
  s3_key = "mn/v1.0.0/lambda-1.0.0-all.jar"

  handler = "dk.fitfit.handler.EventRequestHandler"
  runtime = "java8"

  memory_size = 256

  role = aws_iam_role.event.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "example" {
  name = "serverless_example_lambda"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.lambda.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "lambda" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    actions = [
      "sts:AssumeRole",
    ]

    principals {
      identifiers = [
        "lambda.amazonaws.com"]
      type = "Service"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "event" {
  name = "serverless_example_lambda_event"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.lambda.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "sqs" {
  role = aws_iam_role.event.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.sqs.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "sqs" {
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sqs.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sqs" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    resources = [aws_sqs_queue.sqs.arn]

    actions = [
      "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
      "sqs:DeleteMessage",
      "sqs:GetQueueAttributes",
    ]
  }
}
```

But it doesn't like the SQS policy is picked up because I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Error creating Lambda event source mapping: InvalidParameterValueException: The provided execution role does not have permissions to call ReceiveMessage on SQS
> {
> RespMetadata: {
> StatusCode: 400,
> RequestID: "4971c72f-a2f3-40c2-9d55-fd892b27586b"
> },
> Message_: "The provided execution role does not have permissions to call ReceiveMessage on SQS",
> Type: "User"
> }

Comment: Where do you associate the role created with your lambda functions? There is no code provided for that.

Comment: Why not just create IAM Role 1 and associate it with Lambda 1, and create IAM Role 2 and associate it with Lambda 2?

Comment: @Marcin - I've updated the question with my Lambda's which is also where the roles are attached

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - That's what I'm trying to do. Thanks for the edits by te way

Comment: Sadly, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Where is your `aws_lambda_event_source_mapping`? Which lambda function is used in the source mapping? Both of them?

Comment: @Marcin -  Both Lambda's should have aws_iam_policy_document.lambda but only one should have aws_iam_policy_document.sqs. I didn't think the aws_lambda_event_source_mapping would be relevant. I'll update the question

Comment: @Marcin - That made me see my error. But the credits goes to you. If you make an answer stating that function_name = aws_lambda_function.example.arn should be function_name = aws_lambda_function.event.arn I'll accept it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was due to mistake in `aws_lambda_event_source_mapping`. Instead of

```
function_name = aws_lambda_function.example.arn
```

it should be

```
function_name = aws_lambda_function.event.arn
```